# Quadratic Equations - Problem Solving

Tags: problem-solving, quadratics

> A hall charges $30 per person for a sports banquet when 120 people
>   attend. For every 10 extra people that attend, the hall will decrease
>   the price by 1.5 per person. What number of people will maximize the
>   revenue for the hall?

```
Let x = number of groups of extra-ten people
Let R = total revenue
```

Using this, I created the following quadratic formula:

```
R = -1.5x^2 + 30x + 3600
```

Then I complete the square and determine that the vertex is `(10, 36150)` According to this answer, the number of people which would maximize revenue is 120 + 10 = 130 people; however, my math textbook tells me the answer is 160 people.

What is my mistake? Or is the textbook incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $ x  $ number of people attending then you have

$$f(x)=\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  30x  & \mbox{if } x \leq 120 \\
        3600 + {\sum_{i=121}^x({30-\lfloor {\frac{i-120}{10}}\rfloor}1.5}) & \mbox{if } x >120  \\
 \end{array}
\right.$$

where f is the revenue.

Then you have to differentiate the above function and see where the derivate becomes zero..

Answer (score 1):

The price per person is $30-1.5x$. The number of people is $120+10x$ . You lost that factor $10$